# Disable auto-complete in vscode debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable auto-complete in the vscode debugger?

If there's a way to make it not autocomplete when I'm inside of quotes that would be perfect.[image]

Comment: did you figure it out? this is really painful!

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90520), in File->Preferences->Settings, toggle off `debug.console.historySuggestions`, then history suggestion of debug console will be disabled. In `debug.console`, there should also be an option for command completions, which depends on your debugger plugin. For CodeLLDB, it is `Lldb: Command Completions`. Toggle off it, then the command auto-complete in debug console should be disabled.